# Converting ASCII file to UTF8

Tags: c#, encryption, utf-8

I'm working on an encryption program that passes the text to ASCII and then decrypts for normal text again. The problem is that the decryption, the accents and special characters do not appear. I can not at all (tenteri various codes) convert it to UTF8.

Detail of a file is being generated to store these encryptions and descriptografias.

Here is the code below (not working at all!):

```
        StreamWriter criptografia = new StreamWriter(@"ItensCriptografados.txt", true);
        string palavras = txtcripto.Text;
        txtdescripto.Text = "";
       UTF7Encoding descript = new UTF7Encoding();



        for (int i = 0; i < palavras.Length; i +=3)
        {
            char oi = char.Parse(palavras.Substring(i, 3));
            if (palavras.Substring(i, 3) == "341"){
                i += 3;
                byte[] bytes2 = BitConverter.GetBytes(oi);
                byte[] convertido = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(oi);
                byte[] utf8Array = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.ASCII, Encoding.UTF7, bytes2);
                string s2 = descript.GetString(utf8Array);
            //string s2 = Encoding.UTF7.GetString(bytes2);

               UTF8Encoding utf = new UTF8Encoding();
                byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s);
                byte[] utfArray = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.ASCII, Encoding.UTF8, byteArray);
                string finalString = utf.GetString(utfArray);
            txtdescripto.Text = txtdescripto.Text + s2.ToString();
        }

        }
        criptografia.WriteLine("Texto:{0} . Criptografado:{1}",txtdescripto.Text.ToString(), palavras.ToString());
        criptografia.Close();
```

Comment: Try to replace Encoding.ASCII by System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1") or System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(850));

Comment: Please describe your encryption algorithm in words.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should instead encode and decode the bytes, rather than characters.

Comment: Indeed. But people do like to play with novelty ciphers where everything is a string, usually with unstated restrictions on the inputs.